# What algorithm can I use to determine points within a semi-circle?

Tags: count, points

How can I do this on a grid with several "centers", and therefore, having coincident points that I want to count only once?

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean that you have a semi-circle, and many points, and you want to determine which points are inside the semicircle?

Answer (score 4):

To find out if a point, `P`, is within a semi-circle I would consider a two part test:

1. Is `P` within the radius, `R`,  of the center, `C`?
2. Is `P` in the correct (i.e. occupied) half plane?

Part (1) is easy: compare `(P_x-C_x)^2 + (P_y-C_y)^2` (in 2d, add the Z direction in 3d, of course) with `R^2` (don't bother with the square-roots, they take time and don't add anything).

Part (2) is almost as easy: define the vector `b = B - C` that bisects the semi circle pointing into the occupied half plane. Then compute vector `v = P - C` and take the dot product with `b`. If the result is positive the point is in the occupied half plane, if negative the point is in the unoccupied half place and if 0 the point falls on the dividing line. The dot product in 2d is `v*b = v_x*b_x + v_y*b_y` as usual.